# HUD is eating my RAM

Tags: 13.04, updates, 64-bit, ram, hud

I'm running 13.04 64bit on a Dell Latitude with 8GB RAM. Recently, the HUD search results are being sorted differently, I suppose that's due to Unity updates.
What's worse is that my system is performing very poorly since these changes appeared and my laptop overheats. Running 'top' in a Terminal shows a process called "hud-service" consuming about 50% of my RAM. CPU usage equals.
Does anyone encounter the same and know a solution?
Killing the HUD is not an option, because I use it quite often.

I have now filed a bug report on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1203718

Comment: What about CPU usage?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: I have a similar problem with the HUD on 13.04 64bit, it starts eating close to 1GB of RAM as during regular usage. I Kill the process and restart the HUD-service but then it starts to creep back up.

Comment: Right you are. I have observed the phenomenon during the last days. In the beginning, HUD is fast and not using much of the resources, but after a couple of hours it's getting more and more hungry. I'm going to try and not use the HUD at all during my next office day in order to see if it happens even if the service is only running in the background. After that I'll report the bug.

Comment: I have posted/linked this question at the OMG! Ubuntu! Google Plus community page, I will post any possible fixes that come from there, here. I can't recall if had tried the HUD and it started eating or it just started eating ram on its own through the day.

Comment: FYI: the bug has been confirmed on Launchpad (See my question for the link) because it affects multiple users.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable HUD service using following command.

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/lib/indicator-appmenu/hud-service
```

Reboot your system. Hud will not more run.

Comment: +1 for the answer, but actually I like the HUD and want to keep on using it.

Answer (score 0):

I did not notice any consequences with killing the HUD.
HUD was hogging 8GB on my computer and killing it was a better option than rebooting.
It restarted gracefully.